# How to encrypt / decrypt a text by using RSA method?

Tags: java, string, security, encryption, rsa

I have a simple java code that encrypts and decrypts numbers using the RSA algorithm

If anyone could help me to make this code reads a text (string) from the user and decrypt it instead of only numbers but in a simple way so I can draw a flowchart for the code afterward :)

https://codedost.com/css/java-program-rsa-algorithm/

```
import java.util.*;
import java.math.*;

public class RSA {

public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int p, q, n, z, d = 0, e, i;
    System.out.println("Enter the number to be encrypted and decrypted");
    int msg = sc.nextInt();
    double c;
    BigInteger msgback;
    System.out.println("Enter 1st prime number p");
    p = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter 2nd prime number q");
    q = sc.nextInt();

    n = p * q;
    z = (p - 1) * (q - 1);
    System.out.println("the value of z = " + z);

    for (e = 2; e < z; e++) {
        if (gcd(e, z) == 1) // e is for public key exponent
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    //e should be in the range 1-z
    System.out.println("the value of e = " + e);

    // calculate d
    for (i = 0; i <= 9; i++) {
        int x = 1 + (i * z);
        if (x % e == 0) //d is for private key exponent
        {
            d = x / e;
            break;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("the value of d = " + d);
    c = (Math.pow(msg, e)) % n;
    //Encryptin  C = msg ^e mod n
    System.out.println("Encrypted message is : -");
    System.out.println(c);


    //converting int value of n to BigInteger
    BigInteger N = BigInteger.valueOf(n);
    //converting float value of c to BigInteger
    BigInteger C = BigDecimal.valueOf(c).toBigInteger();

    msgback = (C.pow(d)).mod(N);
    //Decrypt , P = Cˆd mod N , msgback = P
    System.out.println("Derypted message is : -");
    System.out.println(msgback);

}
static int gcd(int e, int z) {
    if (e == 0) {
        return z;
    } else {
        return gcd(z % e, e);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: RSA only works for numbers; but you could, in example convert your string to bytes, and encrypt each byte individually; or group 8 bytes into a long and encrypt long-s; or use other techniques (like adding the previously computed value to the next character being encripted, etc..).

Comment: Usually you would operate on bytes and use a `BigInteger` to do the math.

Comment: (1) max-31-bit p and q, much less max-31-bit n, is much too small to provide any security (2) that method of computing d won't work for non-absurd n even well below 31-bit (3) using Math.pow doesn't work for more than about 52 bits, and doing pow _then_ mod (not combined) for reasonable sizes will take longer than the Earth will exist (4) even with reasonable sizes and working code, unpadded RSA is mostly not secure; that's OT for SO but covered by dozens of Qs on crypto and security stacks (5) these basic mistakes could be avoided by reading wikipedia

Comment: To avoid prohibitive cpu cost for large text, you could have a header to express a master secret delivered with public key encryption, then the remainder of the file with AES from that master secret.

Comment: @Daniele I know that, but unfortunately I don’t have that programming skills :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you already implemented encryption and decryption for single number you can easily extend it and provide support for longer messages. In fact, the only change you need is to perform same operation N times (for each character in input message). Have a look at below code:

```java
import java.util.*;
import java.math.*;

public class Rsa {

    private static final Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    private int p, q, n, z, d = 0, e, i;

    public Rsa() {
        System.out.println("Enter 1st prime number p");
        p = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter 2nd prime number q");
        q = sc.nextInt();

        n = p * q;
        z = (p - 1) * (q - 1);
        System.out.println("the value of z = " + z);

        for (e = 2; e < z; e++) {
            if (gcd(e, z) == 1) // e is for public key exponent
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        //e should be in the range 1-z
        System.out.println("the value of e = " + e);

        // calculate d
        for (i = 0; i <= 9; i++) {
            int x = 1 + (i * z);
            if (x % e == 0) //d is for private key exponent
            {
                d = x / e;
                break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("the value of d = " + d);
    }

    private static int gcd(int e, int z) {
        if (e == 0) {
            return z;
        } else {
            return gcd(z % e, e);
        }
    }

    double encrypt(int msg) {
        //Encrypting  C = msg ^e mod n
        return (Math.pow(msg, e)) % n;
    }

    double[] encrypt(String msg) {
        int[] charactersAsNumbers = new int[msg.length()];
        for(int i = 0; i < msg.length(); i++) {
            charactersAsNumbers[i] = msg.codePointAt(i);
        }
        System.out.println("Plain text as sequence of numbers: " + Arrays.toString(charactersAsNumbers));

        double[] encryptedMsg = new double[msg.length()];
        for(int i = 0; i < charactersAsNumbers.length; i++) {
            encryptedMsg[i] = encrypt(charactersAsNumbers[i]);
        }
        return encryptedMsg;
    }

    BigInteger decrypt(double encrypted) {
        //converting int value of n to BigInteger
        BigInteger N = BigInteger.valueOf(n);
        //converting float value of c to BigInteger
        BigInteger C = BigDecimal.valueOf(encrypted).toBigInteger();

        //Decrypt , P = Cˆd mod N , msgback = P
        return (C.pow(d)).mod(N);
    }

    String decrypt(double[] encrypted) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        for(double encryptedCharacter: encrypted) {
            BigInteger decryptedCharacter = decrypt(encryptedCharacter);
            builder.append(Character.toChars(decryptedCharacter.intValue()));
        }
        return builder.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println("Enter the text to be encrypted and decrypted");
        String msg = sc.nextLine();
        Rsa rsa = new Rsa();

        double[] c = rsa.encrypt(msg);
        System.out.println("Encrypted message is: " + Arrays.toString(c));

        String msgBack = rsa.decrypt(c);
        System.out.println("Decrypted message is: " + msgBack);
    }
}
```

What I did here is:

- Overloaded `encrypt` and `decrypt` methods. Now they support longer messages; `encrypt` accepts `String` parameter and returns `double[]`, `decrypt` accepts `double[]` and returns `String`
- Logic moved to methods without changing original data types and general flow

I know given solution is not optimal but I guess performance and code style aren't critical for you in this case.

Hope it helps you solve your problem.

Edit: I improved logs slightly, here is the sample output (and input):

```
Enter the text to be encrypted and decrypted
Secret.
Enter 1st prime number p
13
Enter 2nd prime number q
19
the value of z = 216
the value of e = 5
the value of d = 173
Plain text as sequence of numbers: [83, 101, 99, 114, 101, 116, 46]
Encrypted message is: [239.0, 43.0, 112.0, 95.0, 43.0, 51.0, 50.0]
Decrypted message is: Secret.
```

Comment: Thank you so much I really appreciate it, but there is a simple error on line 6 public Rsa() can you please tell me how to fix it :( thank u again

Comment: @FtounAlmutairi Could you explain what the problem is? Program compiles and runs successfully on my machine using jdk 11.0.2.

Comment: Thank you so much I tried to change the package name and the whole project on  NetBeans and now it worked thank you so much but I'd like to ask you is the encrypted message appears before the statement "Encrypted message is "?

Comment: and the encrypted message appear as a number not like the original text is there any chance to fix that?

Comment: Ok, I know what you mean: output is correct but logs may be not so obvious. I've edited the code, have a look at the new version and sample output. Everything should be clear now.

Comment: @FtounAlmutairi You're welcome, do not forget to approve my answer if you think it solves your question ;)